# Facebook Open Graph publish action with object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm working on publishing stories with Facebook Open Graph, for this I'm using their JS SDK. Docs is here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview

So the point is to publish for a user : John Smith is **listening** **Shakira** - Lalala on **Mywebsite.**

listening is the action
Shakira is the object

The JS code would be:

```
FB.api(
  'me/mynamespace:listen',
  'post',
  {
    song: "http://mywebsite/shakiramusic"
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

In this page, some others informations will be specified with code like this:

```
<meta property="og:title"  content="Lalala" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="wonderShakira.jpeg" />
```

But, here is my problem. Imagine that I would like to make a Stories like : 
**John Smith is reading page 542 from a BigBook on mywebsite**

The page number is highly variable and so can't be stock in meta property because Facebook won't refresh it in time.

So I would like making something like that:

```
FB.api(
  'me/mynamespace:reading',
  'post',
    {
      object:{
      app_id: 1234567890,
      type: "book",
      url: "http://mywebsite/thebigbook
      title: "The Big Book"
      image: "bigbookcover.png",
      description: "A super book",
      ** page_count:542 **
    }
},
function(response) {
  // handle the response
}
);
```

But of course it's not working and i get an error. May be i misunderstand the principe of custom stories, actions and objects... I hope my problem is clear and you'll be able to help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It's an unknown error. Code 1.

Comment: You may not be able to use listen. Facebook is not currently allowing any more submission for music.listen.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/music.listens maybe this is why you can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, here is the good code:

```
FB.api(
  'me/mynamespace:reading',
  'post',
    {
      book:{
          app_id: 1234567890,
          type: "book",
          title: "The Big Book"
          image: "bigbookcover.png",
          description: "A super book",
          url: "http://mywebsite/thebigbook
          page_count:542
    }
},
function(response) {
  // handle the response
}
);
```

There is two things to consider: 
 you need to send an object call **book** for reading and you need to put the url parameter **in last**, otherwise, Open Graph will get the value in the meta tag. If you put it last, OG will take the parameter that you send.